# Thymeleaf, how to make conditional statement with th:src?

Tags: thymeleaf

If `dish.imageFolder` is not null - it should be

```
<img th:src="@{${dish.imageFolder}}"/>
```

If null - this image

```
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option:

```
<img th:src="${dish.imageFolder != null} ? @{${dish.imageFolder}} : 'https://via.placeholder.com/150'" />
```

I would probably just use `th:if` though, like this:

```
  <img th:if="${dish.imageFolder != null}" th:src="@{${dish.imageFolder}}" />
  <img th:if="${dish.imageFolder == null}" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
```